# Why isn't this java code working?! Generic Stack

Tags: java, generics, stack

I am new to Generics in java and I really need help in this code
it is not compiling i dont know why!
The stack class is:

```
 public class GenericStack<Item>{
    public class Stack {

        private Node first=null;

        private class Node {
            Item item;
            Node next;
        }

        public boolean IsEmpty()
        {
            return first==null;
        }

        public void push (Item item)
        {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = new Node();
            first.item = item;
            first.next = oldfirst;
        }

        public Item pop ()
        {
            Item item=first.item;
            first=first.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the main

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GenericStack<Integer> ob = new GenericStack<Integer>();
    ob.push(5);
    obpush(10);
    ob.push(15);
    while (!ob.IsEmpty())
    {
        int x=ob.pop();
        StdOut.print(x);
    }

  }
}
```

now the error is:

```
  The method push(int) isn't defined for the type GenericStack<Integer>
```

Where did i go wrong?! can anyone explain please to me

Thank you in advance

Comment: `GenericStack` doesn't have the method `push`, only the nested class `Stack` has it.

Comment: Because there is no method which accepts int argument ie push(int).

Comment: I think you are thinking about [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class GenericStack<Item>{
    class Stack {

        private Node first=null;

        private class Node {
            Item item;
            Node next;
        }

        public boolean IsEmpty()
        {
            return first==null;
        }

        public void push (Item item)
        {
            Node oldfirst = first;
            first = new Node();
            first.item = item;
            first.next = oldfirst;
        }

        public Item pop ()
        {
            Item item=first.item;
            first=first.next;
            return item;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GenericStack<Integer> ob = new GenericStack<Integer>();
    GenericStack<Integer>.Stack st=ob.new Stack();
    st.push(5);
    st.push(10);
    st.push(15);
    while (!st.IsEmpty())
    {
        int x=st.pop();
//        StdOut.print(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

  }
}
```

You are calling methods of the inner class. So that using object of outer class you cannot directly call the methods of the inner class. See above code for that.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your `GenericStack` class has no methods. Get rid of the nested class structure and use the generic type parameter for `Stack` directly:

```
public class Stack<Item> {

    private Node first=null;

    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean IsEmpty()
    {
        return first==null;
    }

    public void push (Item item)
    {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
    }

    public Item pop ()
    {
        Item item=first.item;
        first=first.next;
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because method `push` is defined in class `GenericStack.Stack`, not `GenericStack`.  To make it work replace

```
GenericStack<Integer> ob = new GenericStack<Integer> ();
```

with

```
GenericStack<Integer>.Stack ob = new GenericStack.Stack ();
```

Comment: Since it is not a static inner class you need to have a live instance of the enclosing class. so that your second statement should be GenericStack<Integer>.Stack st=outerClassObject.new Stack();

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your code is that you mixed 2 public classes, just changed a little your code, have fun !!

GenericStack.java

```
public class GenericStack<Item> {

    private Node first = null;

    private class Node {
        Item item;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean IsEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public void push(Item item) {
        Node oldfirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = oldfirst;
    }

    public Item pop() {
        Item item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }

}
```

TestGenericStack.java

```
public class TestGenericStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericStack<Integer> ob = new GenericStack<Integer>();
        ob.push(5);
        ob.push(10);
        ob.push(15);
        while (!ob.IsEmpty()) {
            int x = ob.pop();
            System.out.println(x);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra coating of class `Stack` from `GenericStack`.

Thanks!

Comment: This is unnecessary. There is such a thing as [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) in Java, after all.

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary but it's also a waste of memory. `new Integer(5)` creates a new object while `Integer.valueOf(5)` or just `5` both allow for reuse of an existing instance of `Integer`.